# How to count multiple text in multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am Working off a large table in Excel and I want to sort the data into categories. What I’m trying to do is get Excel to count how many times a criteria in column C, D, & E occurs and returns the value. So look through `C:C` pick “Company”, then look through   `D:D` for “Full Time – Temp” and then   `E:E` for a location such as “Factory”. See link to sample table below.

Example:

`G4 =COUNTIFS($C:$C,"company",$D:$D,"full time - temp",$E:$E,"home")` and it returns 0

`I4 =COUNTIFS($C:$C,"company bilingual",$D:$D,"bilingual - FT - perm")` and it will return 3

My problem is column E

If I wanted to return in cell J4 how many “Company Bilingual” are “Bilingual - FT – Perm” and located in “Factory”  I get 0.

I’ve tried using

`J4 =COUNTIFS($C:$C,"company bilingual",$D:$D,"bilingual - FT – perm",$E:$E,"Factory")` but it returns 0 and what I want it to return is 2, which I understand it is saying there is no Factory cell on its own, all the cells that have Factory have 3 items in them e.g Factory - Dallas. So I want to count all the factories in column E but not where the factory is actually located.

In summary what I want to do is find a function or array that will count one unique occurrence in column C, D, and E. If a cell in a column has more than one word I would like to be able to pick one word and ultimately still count all occurrences in the other columns and return a value.

In my research I have come across different suggestions but none that helps my problem.

I hope I've explained my problem, any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Screenshot of table

[image]

Comment: have you tried using wildcards with countifs.

Comment: Can you permit a helper column for a very simple solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you make the criteria table and mention your criteria there as shown by me in the snapshot.Giving due credit to @Harsha Vardhan, his suggestion is correct approach as given in his comments. I have made a fully working example for clear understanding.

For partial string match I used a concatenated string in I2 `="*"&"Factory"&"*"`

Criteria Table is in the Range   `G1:I4` and Results are in the Range `J1:J4`

Formula to be entered in J2 to J4 respectively are as per criteria mentioned in the table.

```
=COUNTIFS($C:$C,$G$2,$D:$D,$H$2,$E:$E,$I$2)  

=COUNTIFS($C:$C,$G$3,$D:$D,$H$3)   

=COUNTIFS($C:$C,$G$4,$D:$D,$H$4,$E:$E,$I$4)
```

Results are as per your requirement as shown in the snapshot.

[image: Results]

**EDIT DATE 23-06-2016**

This has reference to OP's comments on 22nd and 23rd June 2016. There is no change in the formulas. It is required that conditions are put correctly in the criteria table. As per new criterion specified by OP, following snapshot shows that correct results are obtained. Further file [count multiple text 23062016](https://www.dropbox.com/s/swb14d2q2ora1bb/count%20multiple%20text%2023062016.xlsm?dl=0) has been uploaded for perusal.
[image: Snapshot showing results 23-06-2016]

Comment: YES IT WORKED! I've been cracking my head the last few days on how to solve the problem. Well done and thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ben I shall be grateful, if you accept my answer in line with the SO tradition of conveying thanks by ticking green check mark on the left side of the answer below lower triangle. Thanks you have already ticked the answer.

Comment: What if I wanted to exclude $I$2, so that the value that is returned is 1. I tried =COUNTIFS($C:$C,$G$2,$D:$D,$H$2,$E:$E,"<>$I$2") but that doesn't work.

Comment: @Ben It won't work . In column I you have varying strings Factory Dallas, Factory  Atlanta etc. Change them all to Factory only then see whether it works or not.

Comment: That did't work either, any other thoughts? If it helps, this new problem will be done on a different worksheet. So exact same raw data (Column A-E) but different sheet. I tried creating a new criteria table with the complete string *Factory - Atlanta* and input the not equal to operator but no joy there.

Comment: @Ben It works fine. Criteria are to be put properly. Please see my edit to answer on 23-06-2016. I have also uploaded a working file.

Comment: You are right the criteria was not input correctly and it worked when I corrected it, however changing all cells to Factory is probably not efficient since there are 500+ cells involved. I believe this is a different problem so I have asked the question to the SO community please feel free to provide an answer there. Thank you.